# Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have tried this code to return all students with their information in a school.

```
$school=School::where('admin_id',auth()->user()->id)->first();
        return $user=User::with(["studentDetails"=>function($q) use($school){
            $q->where('studentDetails.school_id','=',$school->id);
        },"subscriptionsSatus.courses"])->get();
```

this was my error

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'studentDetails.school_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `student_details` where `student_details`.`student_id` in (79, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 89, 90) and `studentDetails`.`school_id` = 7) in file
```

what I have  done wrong here.. the column name is same.. as Database

Comment: remove studentDetails here $q->where('studentDetails.school_id','=',$school->id); 
$q->where('school_id','=',$school->id); should be ok

Comment: @skorp okay it worked but it returns all users  as studentdetails as null.
how can I avoid this I only need to return users who has school_id =my value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't have to specify the column :

```
$school=School::where('admin_id',auth()->user()->id)->first();
        
return $user=User::with(["studentDetails"=>function($q) use($school){
            $q->where('school_id','=',$school->id);
        },"subscriptionsSatus.courses"])->get();
```

if you want to return only user having this school then :

```
$school=School::where('admin_id',auth()->user()->id)->first();
        
return $user=User::with(["studentDetails"=>function($q) use($school){
            $q->where('school_id','=',$school->id);
        },"subscriptionsSatus.courses"])
->whereHas('studentDetails', function($query){
 $query->where('school_id','=',$school->id);
})->get();
```